# Julia: non-destructively update immutable type variable

Tags: julia, immutability

Let's say there is a type

```
immutable Foo
    x :: Int64
    y :: Float64
end
```

and there is a variable `foo = Foo(1,2.0)`. I want to construct a new variable `bar` using `foo` as a prototype with field `y = 3.0` (or, alternatively non-destructively update `foo` producing a new `Foo` object). In ML languages (Haskell, OCaml, F#) and a few others (e.g. Clojure) there is an idiom that in pseudo-code would look like

```
bar = {foo with y = 3.0}
```

Is there something like this in Julia?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any built-in syntax sugar in this case in Julia. You have to create a function yourself.

Comment: @colinfang I guess it has to be something like a "copy constructor" when I define immutable type with additional keyword arguments...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tricky. In Clojure this would work with a data structure, a dynamically typed immutable map, so we simply call the appropriate method to add/change a key. But when working with *types* we'll have to do some reflection to generate an appropriate new constructor for the type. Moreover, unlike Haskell or the various MLs, Julia isn't statically typed, so one does not simply look at an expression like `{foo with y = 1}` and work out what code should be generated to implement it.

Actually, we *can* build a Clojure-esque solution to this; since Julia provides enough reflection and dynamism that we can treat the type as a sort of immutable map. We can use `fieldnames` to get the list of "keys" in order (like `[:x, :y]`) and we can then use `getfield(foo, :x)` to get field values dynamically:

```
immutable Foo
  x
  y
  z
end

x = Foo(1,2,3)

with_slow(x, p) =
  typeof(x)(((f == p.first ? p.second : getfield(x, f)) for f in fieldnames(x))...)

with_slow(x, ps...) = reduce(with_slow, x, ps)

with_slow(x, :y => 4, :z => 6) == Foo(1,4,6)
```

However, there's a reason this is called `with_slow`. Because of the reflection it's going to be *nowhere near* as fast as a handwritten function like `withy(foo::Foo, y) = Foo(foo.x, y, foo.z)`. If `Foo` is parametised (e.g. `Foo{T}` with `y::T`) then Julia will be able to infer that `withy(foo, 1.)` returns a `Foo{Float64}`, but won't be able to infer `with_slow` at all. As we know, this kills the <strike>crab</strike> performance.

The only way to make this as fast as ML and co is to generate code effectively equivalent to the handwritten version. As it happens, we can pull off that version as well!

```
# Fields

type Field{K} end

Base.convert{K}(::Type{Symbol}, ::Field{K}) = K
Base.convert(::Type{Field}, s::Symbol) = Field{s}()

macro f_str(s)
  :(Field{$(Expr(:quote, symbol(s)))}())
end

typealias FieldPair{F<:Field, T} Pair{F, T}

# Immutable `with`

for nargs = 1:5
  args = [symbol("p$i") for i = 1:nargs]
  @eval with(x, $([:($p::FieldPair) for p = args]...), p::FieldPair) =
      with(with(x, $(args...)), p)
end

@generated function with{F, T}(x, p::Pair{Field{F}, T})
  :($(x.name.primary)($([name == F ? :(p.second) : :(x.$name)
                         for name in fieldnames(x)]...)))
end
```

The first section is a hack to produce a symbol-like object, `f"foo"`, whose value is known within the type system. The generated function is like a macro that takes types as opposed to expressions; because it has access to `Foo` and the field names it can generate essentially the hand-optimised version of this code. You can also check that Julia is able to properly infer the output type, if you parametrise `Foo`:

```
@code_typed with(x, f"y" => 4., f"z" => "hello") # => ...::Foo{Int,Float64,String}
```

(The `for nargs` line is essentially a manually-unrolled reduce which enables this.)

Finally, lest I be accused of giving slightly crazy advice, I want to warn that this isn't all that idiomatic in Julia. While I can't give very specific advice without knowing your use case, it's generally best to have fields with a manageable (small) set of fields and a small set of functions which do the basic manipulation of those fields; you can build on those functions to create the final public API. If what you want is really an immutable dict, you're much better off just using a specialised data structure for that.

Comment: Trying applying this method to my program uncovered, perhaps some reasons why this syntax does not exist in Julia: I'm using "smart constructors" for my data types to pre-compute dependent fields + some parameters are passed down to other structures. So, `fieldnames` wouldn't work. I've implemented what I wanted in a separate type, that constructs the instance of the original type.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `setindex` (without the `!` at the end) implemented in the `FixedSizeArrays.jl` package, which does this in an efficient way.